# Is there a way I can log when python "requests-cache" hits the cache?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm using https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html and I want to know when the cache is hit vs. the web.

Answer (score 10):

According to the source code, there should be a [`.from_cache` flag](https://github.com/reclosedev/requests-cache/blob/master/requests_cache/core.py#L117) set on the response object:

```
In [1]: import requests

In [2]: import requests_cache

In [3]: requests_cache.install_cache('demo_cache')

In [4]: requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com").from_cache
Out[4]: False

In [5]: requests.get("https://stackoverflow.com").from_cache
Out[5]: True
```