# In the Python requests-cache package, how do I detect a cache hit or miss?

Tags: python, python-requests

The Python https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/ library can be used to cache requests. If I'm using requests-cache, how do I detect whether a response came from the cache, or had to be re-fetched from the network?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way I can log when python "requests-cache" hits the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47665450/is-there-a-way-i-can-log-when-python-requests-cache-hits-the-cache)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on [the docs](https://requests-cache.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user_guide/inspection.html#response-details)

> The following attributes are available on responses:
>
> - **`from_cache`: indicates if the response came from the cache**
> - `cache_key`: The unique identifier used to match the request to the response (see Request Matching for details)
> - `created_at`: datetime of when the cached response was created or last updated
> - `expires`: datetime after which the cached response will expire (see Expiration for details)
> - `is_expired`: indicates if the cached response is expired (if, for example, an old response was returned due to a request error)

From their example

```
from requests_cache import CachedSession
session = CachedSession(expire_after=timedelta(days=1))

response = session.get('http://httpbin.org/get')
print(response.from_cache)
```